# Which Standard Deviation formula & Standard Error formula to use to conclude an A/B test

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, mean, standard-deviation, standard-error

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Story:**
Our site has a button whose existing color is Green. While we think the color of the button should be Blue. Around 100k people visit our site daily, and the CTR of the green button is 3%. So, we ran an AB test where we showed the blue button to 1k visitors daily for 30 days (which makes our sample population size to be 30k) and during these days we got 1500 clicks on the blue button, which makes its CTR as 5%.

**Now, the Questions are:**

1. How do we conclude and report the final result?
2. Which Standard Deviation formula & Standard Error formula should we use, of the 2 shown in
   the image above?

Also adding the raw data's image below, for reference:

[image]

Comment: You took a sample from your population of visitors, so you should use the sample standard deviation (s, dividing by N-1), and compute s.e.m. from there as s.e.m. = s/sqrt(N).